# Blender as Python module; link to the correct pythonXX.dll?

Tags: python, scripting

I am the maintainer of a blender as a python module 'bpy' on pip and github.

https://github.com/TylerGubala/blenderpy

I am able to build blender pretty successfully. I have wheels for multiple python versions created. This allows extension authors to install the module `bpy` into a venv for unit testing of their extension, without comprimising their Blender environment.

Currently though, it only works in Python 3.6 (the current version of Python that Blender supports).

I would argue that it could be useful for such extension authors to test their extensions against upcoming versions of Python as they come out.

Would it be possible to link blender against the new python37.dll?

Currently what I am doing is I install bpy into the python 3.7 venv:

```
pip install bpy
```

Then, I start a new Python session and attempt to import the package:

```
import bpy
```

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Then, after copying and pasting python37.dll and renaming the copy to python36.dll, my fears were confirmed, it is trying to use python36.dll:

```
import bpy
```

> ImportError: Module use of python36.dll conflicts with this version of Python

Is there a way to, intuitively, tell blender when its building to target a certain version of Python?

EDIT:

The build scripts can be found in `./vscode/tasks/build_all.bat`

EDIT 2:

Here is an image of the PYTHON variables from CMAKE; I don't see `PYTHON_LIBRARY`, though

[image: Python Variables from CMAKE]

Here is a picture with the grouped variables:

[image: Grouped vars]

Comment: Did you try compiling blender itself against your desired version of Python? You can't just rename DLL's, that almost never works, and in fact here its actively detecting and stopping that.

Comment: Correct, I compiled Blender from sources using Python 3.7 in cmake. The intended goal of copying and renaming the DLL was not to attempt to resolve the issue, it was merely to track down the source of the `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found` error. Thanks for your time

Comment: And you did use your new version of bpy and any other Python modules also built with 3.7? I trust cmake to not do anything strange here, so if built with 3.7 there should not be any 3.6 references at all.

Comment: Sorry could you clarify your suspicions for me? My first step was to enter into the Python 3.7 venv that I created for building purposes. Then, I ran `py setup.py bdist_wheel` (which performs the manual cmake build procedure from the BF reccomendation). After uploading with twine, I created a new 3.7 venv as a test environment, but recieved the above error. Perhaps I'm missing some curcial step.

Comment: The only way to get an error because a module wanted python36.dll is generally for the module you were loading to have been built against that version.

Comment: Leaning a little off-topic as its about building blender.  Post a screenshot of your cmake PYTHON vars (from cmake-gui or similar).

Comment: Do you think manually setting python flags in cmake would remedy it then? I was probably misunderstanding/ taking cmake for granted; I thought once I entered my venv, that would be the built version.

Comment: @batFINGER Is building blender off-topic here? If so, is there some special Blender building stackexchange site or is stackoverflow and IRC the best a man can get?

Comment: [Unfortunately, yes](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399/can-we-please-reconsider-allowing-qa-regarding-blender-build-problems)  Also last time I looked https://blenderarrtists.org had a coding forum. On cmake, checking the generated cmake vars eg (PYTHON_LIBRARY)  will clarify.

Comment: Okay, sorry that it is off topic, I should have checked before hand. If it doesn't get deleted as off topic first, I will take a snapshot of the cmake vars, including PYTHON_LIBRARY, when I have time tonight at home. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @TylerGubala Building blender is off-topic (discussion [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399/can-we-please-reconsider-allowing-qa-regarding-blender-build-problems)). I don't personally understand the technicalities of this question enought to understand if it is fully about building blender, so I will leave it to yourself and others to determine whether this question should remain open. [Dev Talk](https://devtalk.blender.org/) or [Blender Artists](http://blenderartists.org/) might be a possible place to discuss this.

Comment: @Ray This question is almost 100% about building Blender. The scripting aside was more or less a tangent about my motivation in building Blender this way. I will post on blenderartists.org, but I hope you understand my plight that I will be posting about compilation, when almost that entire community is centered around sharing art; the "coding" sections of that forum often go untouched for weeks at a time. Feel free to close the question, I can go there.

Comment: @TylerGubala I did also mention Dev Talk.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about building Blender, which is off-topic. See: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399/can-we-please-reconsider-allowing-qa-regarding-blender-build-problems/400#400

Comment: I know, that has its own share of issues; I won't go into it here (not the place) but I have been on the IRC, Artists and DevTalk before and found the format... lacking, in my own opinion. I'll try all of those. Thanks.

Comment: Check [grouped](http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=a2c12f3dc45d84519b82b258b74563a8)

Comment: @batFINGER Can't seem to find that on Windows... I think this is hardcoded due to SVN.